# Integrating two Orion/CB automatically

Tags: fiware-orion

Is there any way to integrate two CBs automatically? For sample, I just
connect a subscription in another CB node, without any helper?

If not, what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Federation. Have several Context Brokers share the same information through [federating](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Context_Broker_Federation) them.
- Context Providers. Act as [context provider](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Registering_Context_Providers_and_request_forwarding), where one Context Broker holds the actual information while others can serve it (kind of a proxy).

Comment: The solution given by LGM has worked fine. There is just an small detail to be taken in account: the only version of mongo which works with this solution is the recommended 2.4.13. Any newer version crashes when insertions increase upon a determined value.